# Warp Image by Diagonal Sine Wave

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to warp colour image using sin function in OpenCV and I was successful in doing so. However, how can I make a 'diagonal' warping using sine wave?

My code is this:

```
Mat result = src.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++) { // to y
        for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++) { // to x
            for (int ch = 0; ch < 3; ch++) { // each colour
                int offset_x = 0;
                int offset_y = (int)(25.0 * sin(3.14 * j / 150));
                if (i + offset_y < src.rows) {
                    result.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[ch] = src.at<Vec3b>((i + offset_y) % src.rows, j)[ch];
                }
                else
                    result.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[ch] = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }

    imshow("result", result);
```

How can I do this? Not drawing a sine graph, but warping an image.

Solved this! Several times ago, I've received a message by someone who told me that the image is stolen. It was from Google, actually, but I've deleted it to fulfill not to cause any situations. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should look like this:

```
void deform()
{
    float alpha = 45 * CV_PI / 180.0; // wave direction
    float ox = cos(alpha);
    float oy = sin(alpha);
    
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("F:/ImagesForTest/lena.jpg");

    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; i+=8)
    { 
            cv::line(src, cv::Point(i, 0), cv::Point(i, src.rows),cv::Scalar(255,255,255));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; j += 8)
    { 
        cv::line(src, cv::Point(0,j), cv::Point(src.cols,j), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    }


    cv::Mat result = src.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++)
    { // to y
        for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++)
        { // to x
            float t =(i * oy)+ (j * ox); // wave parameter
            for (int ch = 0; ch < 3; ch++)
            { // each colour
                int offset_x =ox* (int)(25.0 * (sin(3.14 * t/ 150)));
                int offset_y =oy* (int)(25.0 * (sin(3.14 * t / 150)));
                if (i + offset_y < src.rows && j + offset_x < src.rows && i + offset_y >=0 && j + offset_x>=0)
                {
                    result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[ch] = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(i + offset_y, j + offset_x )[ch];
                }
                else
                    result.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[ch] = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }

    cv:: imshow("result", result);
    cv::imwrite("result.jpg", result);
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

The result:
[image]

BTW, may be better to use cv::remap ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try this in tomorrow. And could you explain why 'remap' is useful in computer vision field? I'm studying on my own & felt quite frustrating

Comment: cv::remap allows you to apply geometric transformation of image space according to x and y maps. Maps describes where pixel from current map coordinates should be placed. remap also do interpolations and it highly optimized. Classical usage is applying lens undistortion. But can be used for applying distortion effects, as in your case.